# Creating version-specific Ubuntu Mirror

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, mirror

I have been tasked with creating a local Ubuntu mirror for my company. However, we do not need the entire archive (like 10.04, 12.04). I am currently following this tutorial from the Ubuntu community: [Rsyncmirror](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror)
How would I go about excluding specific packages/distros (like 14.04, 16.04) from the mirror?

Answer (score 1):

Upon doing more research, I discovered this method:
[Debmirror](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror)
Debmirror allows for only downloading specific versions, (ie Trusty), as well as excluding specific package categories (ie games).